# Will multiple requests accessing the same variable will cause a conflict?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, worker

Trying something out I'm not very familiar with:

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'redis'

$redis = # Connect Redis
$log = []

Thread.new do
  while true do
    $redis.set 'test', $log.pop
  end
end

post '/' do
    $log.push(request.user_agent)
    "ok"
end
```

Say that I get a couple of thousand hits per second to `/`. What happens if push and pop are called simultaneously on `$log`?

Will raising the priority of the worker thread help anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use use a [Queue](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/thread/rdoc/Queue.html) for this, as it is meant for cross-thread communication. It is thread-safe, and keeps the Thread from busy-waiting as [`Queue#pop`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/thread/rdoc/Queue.html#method-i-pop) will suspend the thread if there is nothing on the queue instead of looping till the OS takes control away.

```
require 'redis'
require 'sinatra'
require 'thread'

$redis = # Connect Redis
$log = Queue.new

Thread.new do
  while entry = $log.pop
    $redis.set 'test', entry
  end
end

post '/' do
  $log.push(request.user_agent)
  "ok"
end
```

However, what you have won’t be an issue (as far as unexpected results go—performance will be a problem) because of MRI’s [GIL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Interpreter_Lock) (other Ruby implementations without a GIL may have issues, though). Also, it would be best to avoid using global variables.